# Cant display row in an HTML table using angular ng-repeat and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an HTML table that expands or collapse depending if the user clicks on a row, the main record is the "parent" row, if you click it you'll see a child row that displays some records, my issue is that I add a third row that should display by default because the child is hidden until you click on the parent but that third row wont appear and I cant figure out the problem =(

Here's my [example](https://jsfiddle.net/p7ew017u/) in a fiddle and below youll see my directive.

```
angular
.module('app',[])
.controller('DataCtrl',DataCtrl)
.directive('drillDown',drillDown);

 function DataCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.category = [
            {
                "desc": "CATEGORY 1",
                "LW$": "45",
                "LW": "-4%",
                "L4W": "-15.7%",
                "L13W": "24%",
                "L52W": "-6%"
            }
        ]

        $scope.subcat = [
            {
                "desc": "SUB CATEGORY 1",
                "LW$": "45",
                "LW": "-4%",
                "L4W": "-15.7%",
                "L13W": "24%",
                "L52W": "-9%"
            },
            {
                "desc": "SUB CATEGORY 2",
                "LW$": "15",
                "LW": "4.2%",
                "L4W": "1.7%",
                "L13W": "-2.4%",
                "L52W": "-65%"
            },
            {
                "desc": "SUB CATEGORY 3",
                "LW$": "767",
                "LW": "4.2%",
                "L4W": "9.7%",
                "L13W": "-2.4%",
                "L52W": "-21%"
            },
            {
                "desc": "SUB CATEGORY 4",
                "LW$": "21",
                "LW": "14.2%",
                "L4W": "1.7%",
                "L13W": "-42.4%",
                "L52W": "-34%"
            }
        ];
    }

    function drillDown() {

     var directive = {
     restrict: 'A',
    link: link
    };

    return directive;

    function link(scope,element) {

     var table = $('.categories-table');

     table.each(function() {
        var $table = $(this);
        $table.find('.parent').each(function(){
            if($(this).nextUntil('.parent', ".child").length > 0){
                $(this).children('td:first').html('+');
            }
        });
        $table.find('.child').each(function(){
            if($(this).nextUntil('.child', ".grandson").length > 0){
                $(this).children('td:first').html('+');
            }
        });

        var $childRows = $table.find('tbody tr').not('.parent').hide();
        $table.find('button.hide').click(function() {
            $childRows.hide();

        });
    });
    element.on('click',function(){
        if($(this).parent().hasClass('parent') == true)
        {
            console.log("----Parent");
            if ($(this).text() == "+")
                $(this).text("-")
            else
                $(this).text("+");

            $(this).parent().nextUntil('.parent', ".child").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
            $(this).parent().nextUntil('.parent', ".grandson").hide("fast");
            $(this).parent().nextUntil('.parent', ".child").each(function(){

                if($(this).children('td:first').text() == '-')
                    $(this).children('td:first').text('+');
            });
        }
        else if($(this).parent().hasClass('child') == true)
        {
            console.log("----Child");
            if ($(this).text() == "+")
                $(this).text("-")
            else
                $(this).text("+");
            $(this).parent().nextUntil('.child',    ".grandson").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
        }
    });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I recommend you to read this topic: ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Obviously you are using jquery+angular in a wrong way. And there is a logic error in your jQuery code.

If you want to solve problem in angular-way:

One possible solution is to use scope variables or object variables and ng-show directive.

Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/p7ew017u/4/

```
<td ng-class="expand" ng-click="d.expanded = !d.expanded">+</td>
```

And one more thing: tables are not very good for displaying tree structures (like categories, subcategories, subsubcategories, etc). It is better to use lists (ul, ol)

Comment: Thanks for your time, I know that is not the best way and I'm planning to improve my version but now for time issues I need to solve it...

Wich is my logic issue in my jquery? :(

Comment: It's here `var $childRows = $table.find('tbody tr').not('.parent').hide();` You hide all rows with class not `.parent` and last row hasnt `.parent`

Comment: One more question, what if I want to add a new level, like sub. sub category according to your example how can I manage that?

Comment: The best way is to build tree of categories, i.e. `[{title: "Category1", children: [{title: "SubCategory1", children: [...] }, {...}]}, {...}]`. And in template use nested <ul> with ng-repeat